# Getting this error org.json.JSONException: Value at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObjecton parsing

Tags: java, android, android-json

I am getting this error on parsing json. Can anyone help me to solve this.

```
  {
"website": [
    "http://www.example.com",
    "https://buy.example.com"
],
"number": [
    "4546",
    "54256456"
],
"email": [
    "exam@gmail.com",
    "example@gmail.com"
],
"address": [
    "any adddress here",
    "Address 2"
]
  }
```

Anyone help me to how exactly parse this json...

Json Parsing code

```
             String JSON_STRING = response.body().string();
                    Log.e("json_string", JSON_STRING.toString());
                    //Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Response : "+JSON_STRING, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject( JSON_STRING );
                    JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray( "website" );

                        for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject website = jsonArray.getJSONObject( i );
                            Log.e("website", website.toString());
                        }
```

Comment: Please post JSON parsing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
 try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray websites = jsonObject.getJSONArray("website");
        for (int i = 0; i < websites.length(); i++) {
            Log.d("TAG", websites.getString(i));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, i got the answer and i commented below.. Your answer is also correct i used the same approach...

Answer (score 1):

```java
// for email array and response variable is your jsonObject coming from server
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("email")
for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
   //get email one by one 
   String email = jsonArray.getString(i)
}
```

Let me know if it is working.

Comment: JSONObject object = new JSONObject( response.body().string() );
                        JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("email");
                        for(int i = 0 ;i < jsonArray.length();i++){
                      
                            String email = jsonArray.getString(i);
                            Log.e("emailjson", email.toString());
                        }

Comment: ok i thought you are getting response from server in jsonObject not in string otherwise we have to convert string to jsonObject.